# Elastic search XContent Provider

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Help required on the below exception.
Intermittent error with elastic search restHighlevel client.

we were not able to reproduce this in local.

`

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.elasticsearch.plugins.spi.NamedXContentProvider: Provider org.elasticsearch.client.indexlifecycle.IndexLifecycleNamedXContentProvider not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.getProvidedNamedXContents(RestHighLevelClient.java:1887)
```

`

Answer (score 1):

I recently experienced this same issue when trying to use the high level client as part of a more complex application. Using the client in a standalone project worked fine however. I'm still tracking down the cause of the issue, but how I fixed it was by modifying the high level client source code to explicitly set the class loader to be used by `ServiceLoader.load`. Specifically, the change I made was to the `getProvidedNamedXContents()` method in the `RestHighLevelClient` class:

Original:

```
static List<NamedXContentRegistry.Entry> getProvidedNamedXContents() {
    List<NamedXContentRegistry.Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    for (NamedXContentProvider service : ServiceLoader.load(NamedXContentProvider.class)) {
        entries.addAll(service.getNamedXContentParsers());
    }
    return entries;
}
```

Modified:

```
static List<NamedXContentRegistry.Entry> getProvidedNamedXContents() {
    List<NamedXContentRegistry.Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    Class<NamedXContentProvider> namedXContentProviderClass = NamedXContentProvider.class;
    for (NamedXContentProvider service : ServiceLoader.load(namedXContentProviderClass, namedXContentProviderClass.getClassLoader())) {
        entries.addAll(service.getNamedXContentParsers());
    }
    return entries;
}
```

After rebuilding the client with these changes the issue no longer occurred for me. I hope this helps